# Permission denied (publickey) when connecting using ProxyCommand

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Here's my SSH config file:

```
Host bastion
  HostName public-ip
  User user
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host target
  HostName private-ip
  User user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand ssh -A bastion -W %h:%p
```

If I connect first to bastion `$ ssh bastion` and then from there to target `$ ssh private-ip` it works as expected. However, when I try to connect from localhost directly to target by jumping via bastion, I'm getting `user@private-ip: Permission denied (publickey).` error.

I ran `ssh -v` and here are the last few lines of the debug info:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/User.Name/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxx explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/User.Name/.ssh/id_rsa RSA-CERT SHA256:xxx explicit agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@private-ip: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any pointers on how to properly configure agent forwarding so that I jump directly to target host without having to first connect explicitly to bastion?